# Sort queryset by added field

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I'm trying to add an extra field to the instances of my queryset and then sort the set by the new field.
But I get a field error( `Cannot resolve keyword 'foo' into field. Choices are: ...` )

My view(abstract):

```
def view(request):
    instances = Model.objects.all()
    for counter, instance in enumerate(instances):
        instance.foo = 'bar' + str(counter)
    instances.order_by('foo')  #this line causes trouble
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'instances': instance})
```

My template:

```
{% for instance in instances %}
    {{instance.foo}}
{% endfor %}
```

If I leave out the `order_by` line the templates renders as expected, so the field seems to be there.

So why do I get a field error?
It would be awesome, if somebody could help me to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

---

I found a possible solution to change the template to

`{% for instance in instances|dictsort:'foo' %}`

and that works fine, but from what I understand there should be as little logic as possible in the view, so I figure sorting should be done in the view.
Or is this actually the right way?

Comment: Because it is not a field, you added an extra attribute to the objects. But that does not matter. A queryset deals with a query in the first place. If you call `.order_by` you construct a new `QuerySet` on that model. Since `foo` is not a field, you can not sort on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that clarifies it alot.  
So `order_by` actually results in another call to the database and of course the field isn't there, so I get the error.  
How would I sort by the new attribute?
- Edit: Just saw your answer, that explains it.

Comment: with a Python sort function, like `sorted(..)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django ORM aims to construct *database* queries. As a result, you can only query on what a *database* "knows". Methods, properties, or attributes you added yourself are unknown to the database. The `.order_by` thus has no effect, since you "patched" the objects in the `instances` queryset.

If you however call an `instances.order_by` you construct a *new* queryset. This queryset takes the context of the parent, and thus represents a (slightly) modified *query*, but again, a query. Whether the old queryset is already evaluated or patched, is of no importance.

Furthermore even if there was a column `foo`, it would not help, since the `instance.order_by` does *not* order the `instance` queryset, it constructs a new one, one that looks approximately like the old one, except that the rows are ordered.

You thus will have to sort in Python now. You can for example construct a list of *ordered* elements with `sorted(..)`, like:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def view(request):
    instances = Model.objects.all()
    for counter, instance in enumerate(instances):
        instance.foo = 'bar' + str(counter)
    mydata = sorted(instances, key=attrgetter('foo'))
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'instances': mydata})
```

So now `mydata` is no longer a `QuerySet`, but a *vanilla* `list`. Furthermore note that ordering in a database might be *slightly* different than ordering in Python. In Python exceptions can occur if not all elements have the same type, and furthermore it is not guaranteed that the semantics behind the order relation is exactly the same.

Comment: That works, thanks for that. I have now implemented that everywhere in my code, but when I try that to sort the options of a ManyToMany form field I get an attribute error( `'list' object has no attribute 'all'`).   
I try to limit the choices with `form.fields['instances'].querset=mydata` . Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @HahaMuntz: in case a queryset is necessary, then you can not do this. Then you probably better add an extra `foo` field to the database, and update it regularly with the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The new attribute in the Python Objects does not exist in the database and only in those instances. `order_by` changes the queryset and not your current list of objects stored in memory.

One approach would be to use the builtin python sorting functions in the view like: `sorted` or even `list.sort()`.